# How to convert string duration to ISO 8601 duration format? (e.g. "30 minutes" to "PT30M")

Tags: php, duration, iso8601, dateinterval

There are plenty of questions asking how to do this the other way (converting **from** this format), but I can't find anything on how to output in the ISO 8601 duration format in PHP.

So I have a heap of duration strings in human readable format - I want to convert them into the ISO 8601 format on the fly to print the durations for HTML5 microdata. Below is a sample of some of the strings coming in, and how they should be formatted

```
"1 hour 30 minutes" --> PT1H30M
"5 minutes" --> PT5M
"2 hours" --> PT2H
```

I can push the string into an interval object in PHP:

```
date_interval_create_from_date_string("1 hour 30 minutes");
```

but there doesn't seem to be a ISO 8601 output option

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd convert it to a number first, then work with that.

First, use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php):

```
$time = strtotime("1 hour 30 minutes", 0);
```

Then you can parse it for duration, and output in `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` format. I'd use the following method (inspired by http://csl.sublevel3.org/php-secs-to-human-text/):

```
function time_to_iso8601_duration($time) {
    $units = array(
        "Y" => 365*24*3600,
        "D" =>     24*3600,
        "H" =>        3600,
        "M" =>          60,
        "S" =>           1,
    );

    $str = "P";
    $istime = false;

    foreach ($units as $unitName => &$unit) {
        $quot  = intval($time / $unit);
        $time -= $quot * $unit;
        $unit  = $quot;
        if ($unit > 0) {
            if (!$istime && in_array($unitName, array("H", "M", "S"))) { // There may be a better way to do this
                $str .= "T";
                $istime = true;
            }
            $str .= strval($unit) . $unitName;
        }
    }

    return $str;
}
```

The result: http://codepad.org/1fHNlB6e

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simplified version of Eric's `time_to_iso8601_duration()` function. It doesn't loose precision (365 days approximation of a year) and is about 5x faster. The output is less pretty but still ISO 8601 compatible according to [this](http://www.ostyn.com/standards/scorm/samples/ISOTimeForSCORM.htm) page.

```
function iso8601_duration($seconds)
{
    $days = floor($seconds / 86400);
    $seconds = $seconds % 86400;

    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $seconds = $seconds % 3600;

    $minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
    $seconds = $seconds % 60;

    return sprintf('P%dDT%dH%dM%dS', $days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to write function based on the [DateInterval](https://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object. The [ISO 8601 duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is well described.

The advantage of this approach is that it only outputs the relevant (present) representations and it supports empty durations (commonly denoted as `'PT0S'` or `'P0D'`).

```
function dateIntervalToISO860Duration(\DateInterval $d) {
    $duration = 'P';
    if (!empty($d->y)) {
        $duration .= "{$d->y}Y";
    }
    if (!empty($d->m)) {
        $duration .= "{$d->m}M";
    }
    if (!empty($d->d)) {
        $duration .= "{$d->d}D";
    }
    if (!empty($d->h) || !empty($d->i) || !empty($d->s)) {
        $duration .= 'T';
        if (!empty($d->h)) {
            $duration .= "{$d->h}H";
        }
        if (!empty($d->i)) {
            $duration .= "{$d->i}M";
        }
        if (!empty($d->s)) {
            $duration .= "{$d->s}S";
        }
    }
    if ($duration === 'P') {
        $duration = 'PT0S'; // Empty duration (zero seconds)
    }
    return $duration;
}
```

An example:

```
echo dateIntervalToISO860Duration(
    date_diff(
        new DateTime('2017-01-25 18:30:22'), 
        new DateTime('2019-03-11 07:12:17')
    )
);
```

Output: `P2Y1M13DT12H41M55S`