# PHP convert time into a Time Period

Tags: php, string, time, intervals, period

There appears to be a lot of info converting a time period into a time, but not the other way around.

An example of what I need to do, is convert say 120 minutes into P0DT2H0M0S.
And 13:10 into P0DT13H10M0S.
And 120 minutes into PT2H0M0S.

Any quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: I would use Date/Time functions.  Get one current time, modify the time with `DateTime::modify()`, then find the difference with `DateTime::diff()`, then you can output the format however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the format you're describing is the ISO 8601 date/time format.  [Here's how it describes intervals.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals)

In the PHP documentation for the `DateInterval` class, someone has shared an example of how you might convert a string into ISO 8601 in an object-oriented way:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#113415

And here is someone else's solution, using functional rather than object-oriented date methods:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13301472/2119660

Comment: Cheerz. That looks like I can work with that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, to get ISO-8601 time interval duration, is with method [`createFromDateString`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php)

## Use:

```php
echo getISO8601duration_withZeros("3 year 20 day 15 minute"); # P3Y0M20DT0H15M0S
echo getISO8601duration_withZeros("1 hour 120 minutes");      # P0Y0M0DT1H120M0S
echo getISO8601duration_withZeros("7 year 5 month 3 day");    # P7Y5M3DT0H0M0S

# 13:10 example
$dt = new DateTime('13:10');
$interval_spec = "{$dt->format('H')} hour {$dt->format('i')} minute";
echo getISO8601duration_withZeros($interval_spec);            # P0Y0M0DT13H10M0S
```

## Function:

```php
function getISO8601duration_withZeros($interval_spec) {
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString($interval_spec);
    return $interval->format('P%yY%mM%dDT%hH%iM%sS');
}
```

## Demonstration:

- [examples with zeros](https://eval.in/58312) (code above);
- [examples without zeros](https://eval.in/58313);
- [examples with zeros, with recalculated carry over points](https://eval.in/58314);
- [examples without zeros, with recalculated carry over points](https://eval.in/58315).